# Подсчёт количества слов в файле

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Есть задача: нужно определить количество символов, слов и строк в одном файле. Первый и последний пункты выполнены, теперь ломаю голову, что делать со вторым.
Вот код:

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

public class Testament 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        File              file = null;
        LineNumberReader  buff = null;
        FileReader        fr   = null;
        Stack             stack;
        try
        {
            stack = new Stack(); 
            file  = new File("c:","1.txt");
            fr    = new FileReader(file); 
            buff  = new LineNumberReader(fr);  
            String s;
            while((s=buff.readLine())!=null)
            {              
                    //System.out.println("*"+buff.getLineNumber()+"*"+"   "+s);
                    stack.push(s.toString());
            }

            System.out.println("Количество символов: "+file.length());
            System.out.println("Количество строк: "+stack.getSize());

        }
        finally
        {
            if(fr!=null)
                fr.close();
            if(buff!=null)
                fr.close();
        }

    }

}

class Stack
{

    private ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void push(String lnre)
    {
        list.add(lnre);
    }        
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
       return list.toString(); 
    }   
    public int getSize()
    {
        return list.size();
    }                                 
}
```

Собственно, если конкретнее, хотелось бы узнать, можно ли как нибудь выделить отдельные слова из элементов коллекции или этот путь изначально неверный.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

символы значит посчитал?) со словами, наверно, еще проще, просто, бежишь тем же циклом и если встречаешь разделитель(delimiter) ' ' - то счетчик +1.

Comment: я понимаю, что способ, мягко говоря, шаманский, однако я начал изучать java совсем недавно, потому много не знаю. Может подскажете с помощью чего данную задачу решить более грамотно?

Comment: Вполне грамотно.

Comment: можно сделать красиво - читать по строке, так как у тебя уже написано, а потом просто String[] arr = s.split(" "); и вывести результат, System.out.println(arr.length());

Comment: Ясно. Буду пробовать. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотри в сторону класса FileTokenizer

Answer (score 2):

я бы посоветовал использовал regexp

[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+ //регулярное выражение слова(или союза, например "и"), ну и в случае если используются слова более хитрой конструкции - то используем более хитрую регулярку.  
  Все нужное можно найти в javadoc по классам Pattern и Matcher.

Кусок кода будет выглядеть так

```
final String WORD = "[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+";

int i=0;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(WORD);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(externalText);//указываем свой текст
while (matcher.find()) {
    i++;
}
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: ты хоть понял что ты предлагаешь? я, где-то на форуме читал, что-то типа, "если у тебя есть проблема и ты пытаешься ее решить с помощью регулярки, то у тебя уже две проблемы", так вот тут она очень точно подходит

Comment: 2 @Gorets: а вы не думали что лучше один раз в жизни потратить неделю на изучения этой "проблемы". и потом пользоватся этими знаниями вместо того чтоб придумывать велосипед?

Comment: @Gorets, дело в том что регулярками придется пользоваться не один и даже не два раза, лучше 1 раз с ними наиграться вдоволь и все уяснить, чем писать костыль каждый раз.

Comment: я не говорю, что их не стоит знать, я к тому - что лучше выбирать оптимальные пути решения для каждой задачи, а для конкретно этой - это не лучший способ. Имхо, к регуляркам надо подходить внимательно, а не пытаться все и везде "вытянуть" шаблоном, так как даже в обычной проверке имейла, которую делают регуляркой, не всегда можно все предусмотреть (в нэте есть идеальная регулярка для мейла =) ) и тогда уже стоит применять конечный автомат.

Comment: @Gorets афоризмы это круто, но конструктивной критики я с вашей стороны не увидил. в чем недостатки этого варианта? какой вариант вы предлагаете?

Comment: @Gorets, нужно уяснить какие задачи можно решать с помощью regexp'ов, а какие нельзя. Если бы regexp'ы были не нужны - их бы просто не вводили бы.

Comment: "скоро, 1 января - новый 2012 год" ваша регулярка, уже его не посчитает правильно. мой вариант выше.

Comment: таки да, прошу прощения, вместо круглых скобок квадратные. Обновил ответ. Всего 4 слова.

Comment: я бы советовал использовать регулярки опираясь на правило - "по умолчанию запрещено все, кроме...", т.е. стараться проверить данные только на определенный в регулярке шаблон, в данном случае, они не защищают от подводных камней

Comment: в первых, когда мы говорим о regexp то мы говорим не о регекспе приведенном в ответе а вообще, об абстракном выражении которое позволяет сделать все.

а использовать или не использовать решать надо исходя из того насколько сложнее и больше времени надо на реализацию задачи с использованием regexp и без. очень часто шалька весов склоняется в сторону противоположною от regexp. но я более чем уверен что в большинстве случаев это из за того что люди плохо в них разбираются. ведь написать код проще! (замкнутый цикл не так ли?)

Answer (score 1):

я бы организовал проверку так:
в цикле пока не конец строки (файла)

если после пропуска следующие два символа не равны пропуска, то счетчик слов +1, но этот алгоритм дает ошибку на 1, поэтому в начало строки (файла) необходимо добавить символ пробела

Comment: т.е. проверять каждый символ? если пробел, то проверять следующие 2 символа, если они не равны пробелу, то +1. Зачем впереди ставить дополнительный пробел я так и не понял, зачем проверять 2 символа после пробела - тоже не понятно =) мне до сих пор нравится мой вариант)

Comment: пробел с начала добавляю, для того чтобы корректно засчиталось первое слово, проверять следующие два символа нужно, чтобы учитывались слова только с 2 и более букв. а вообще этот метод эффективен для обработки небольшого строки символов.
а для объемного файла этот метод не подходит

я думаю тут нужно бы было использовать что-то типа оператора "найти  символ, начиная с позиции"

Comment: так задача же не стоит найти слово, надо просто кол-во посчитать, вообще плохой вариант, он же не посчитает слова типа, "и, в, я..", а это же неправильно =)